# The probability of a number appearing in an approximation of an irrational number?

Tags: probability, infinity, irrational-numbers, pi

I was wondering if for the number Pi some numbers are more likely to appear than others, for example 3.141594 ... The number 1 appears twice does that mean that the probability for the number 1 appearing is greater than for others? This question doesn't have to be specific to Pi alone, it can be applied to any irrational number or infinity I think.

Comment: We don't even know that every digit appears infinitely often in the expansion of $\pi$. (We conjecture that it is so - and more strongly, that they appear equally often, in some precise sense - but we have no proof, and our best heuristics are generally, "That is the case in 'most' numbers, and we have no reason to expect that $\pi$ is exceptional in that regard")

Comment: If you search the site for "pi normal" you will find a number of questions on this topic.

Comment: Some transcendental numbers (thus irrational) truncated do have predictable digits such as the [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant)

Comment: @Christopher this is great, closest to what I've been looking for, I wanted use transcendental numbers in my question but I don't know enough about them to properly use the term.

Answer (score 0):

For $\pi$ the answer is not known...as far as I am aware, nothing out there would suggest that the digits are distributed non-uniformly.  Here is an article which, among other things, gives a histogram of the occurrence digits in the first trillion digits of $\pi$:

http://www.ams.org/samplings/math-history/hap-6-pi.pdf

Still, a trillion is finite and nobody knows what happens as you go further and further out.

For other irrationals, there certainly can be non-uniform distributions.  .101001000100001...  for example uses only 0's and 1's (a lot more 0's!).

Comment: How do they represent those "non-uniform distributions" in a number which continues forever?

Comment: You are correct in thinking that this is not clear.  The "best" case is when the picture is stable...truncate your number (at N digits, say) and compute the distribution and then push N to infinity.  It can happen that the probability of each digit's occurrence reaches a nice well defined limit.  Doesn't always give satisfactory results.  For my (transcendental) example .101001000100001...  the 1's get so so sparse that the limit (the probability of a given entry being a 1) vanishes.

Comment: that's interesting thanks!

Comment: If you want, say, the a transcendental number where, in the limit, every digit is either 4 or 5 with equal probability, you could take, e.g., .14151441551444155514444155551....